# find minimum from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and I am trying to figure out how to get my program to find the minimum after it reads specific columns and each rows from the file. Can anyone help me with this?

```
This is how an example of how my text file looks like:

05/01   80     2002     5       1966    19   2000   45     2010   
06/22   77     1980     4       1945    22   1986   58     2000

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Day     Max  Year      Min      Year     Max   Year   Min    Year

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
08/01   79     2002     8       1981     28   1900    54    1988   
08/02   79     1989     5       1971     31   1994    60    1998
```

This is my code(below) that I have so far.

```
def main () 
    file = open ('file.txt', 'r')
    for num in file.read().splitlines():
       i = num.split()

       if len(i) > 5:
           print('Day:{}\n' .format(i[0]))
           print('Year:{}\n' .format(i[2]))
           print('Lowest Temperature:{}'.format(i[1]))
```

This is the output I get from my code. (it prints out text as well) :

```
Day:Day
Year:Year
Lowest Temperature:Max

Day: 3/11
Year:1920
Lowest Temperature:78

Day:11/02
Year:1974
Lowest Temperature:80

Day:11/03
Year:1974
Lowest Temperature:74
```

I am trying to find the lowest temperature from my text file and print out the day and the year associated with that temp. My output should look like this. Thanks to everyone who is willing to help me with this.

```
Day:10/02      
Year:1994                  
Lowest Temperature:55
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your current method to read the file into lines, then split each line into individual columns.

You can then make use of `min()`, using the column containing the minimum temperature (in this case column 3) as the key to `min()`.

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
  data = f.read().splitlines()
  data = [i.split() for i in data if any(j.isdigit() for j in i)]
  data = min(data, key=lambda x: int(x[3]))
  print('Day: {}\nYear: {}\nLowest Temperature: {}' .format(data[0], data[2], data[3]))
```

Output for your sample file:

```
Day: 06/22
Year: 1980
Lowest Temperature: 4
```

Comment: can you get to the same output using the min function?

Comment: I tried to change the code to fit with my text file and I am getting an error do you think there is a simpler way to find the lowest temperature?